# React Native Debugger on Expo SDK 48

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, react-native-debugger

I can't run React Native Debugger from Android Studio< Expo SDK 48. There is no Debug Remote JS item in the developer menu, but I have the Open JS Debugger item. When I select it, Devtools is revealed. But in React Native Debugger my device not connected on my port 19000.

Im read documentation and install many librarys and not working yet.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue. I found this solution and it works for me

app.json configuration

```json
"jsEngine": "hermes",
"ios": {
   "jsEngine": "jsc",
   "supportsTablet": true
},
```

and run project with `npx expo start --localhost` command

source: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/754#issuecomment-1469852938

Comment: I am on MAC OS Monterey, and using the method will not show the open remote debugger, and even cause "open JS debugger" disappear from the dev, I am not saying your solution is not wrong, I am just saying that it is not working on my env after 5 months

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that adding `"jsEngine": "jsc"` in the `app.json` under `"android"` and `"ios"`, then RND will start working again.